# Scale y axis and set ytick labels in a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to explain my query with an example, here's a sample code snippet

```py
x = [i for i in range(1, 129)]
y = [i**2 for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

I want the scale the y axis so that it shows only three equally spaced ytick labels: [0, 5000, 15000], for this I used matplotlib's `set_yticks` functionality:

```py
x = [i for i in range(1, 129)]
y = [i**2 for i in x]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks([0, 7500, 15000], [0, 5000, 15000])
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

While the ytick labels are showing up as I wanted, the curve is unaltered, I expect the curve to scale itself according to the new ytick labels. I do not want to change xtick labels in the plot. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How do you want to have equal spacing for `[0, 5000, 15000]` on a linear scale? You want to have `5000 = 10000`?

Comment: I believe the curve did scale accordingly, you just can't tell because the curve is so consistent.

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks, my bad, I didn't understand the issue correctly. It's clear now.

Comment: @AnnZen : No it doesn't. All the code is doing is to replace the **tick labels**. You can very well replace `plt.yticks([0, 7500, 15000], [0, 5000, 15000])` by `plt.yticks([0, 7500, 15000], ['Trump', 'Putin', 'Hillary'])`. The curve will still look the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) here for equally spaced *Y-Axis*

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
plt.plot(x,y) #x,y I used are from the question itself.
ax= plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(7500))
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track...

```py
x = [i for i in range(1, 129)]
y = [i**2 for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks([0, 7500, 15000])
plt.show()
```

Should give 3 equally spaced y-ticks.

And

```py
x = [i for i in range(1, 129)]
y = [i**2 for i in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks([0, 5000, 15000])
plt.show()
```

Gives the y-ticks you mentioned, but they won't be evenly spaced.